# Hide overflow only for background

Tags: html, css

I have a background image placed in div, i set it's width to 110% so it will be bigger, however I need to hide it's overflow, the problem is that if I hide overflow in html or body then overflow of my content is also not visible.

I made this demonstration, let's say image is background and white division is content wrapper. How can I make my browser to scroll content wrapper, but not image.

http://jsfiddle.net/t3PXn/

Comment: Did you try `background-image`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your image as background in the body, with background-position fixed.
Problem solved

Comment: That's not an option, I can't set opacity and 110% size then. However, I set the div position to fixed and now it's working as intended.

Comment: CSS resizing is evil! Why do you need opacity? Modify your image accordingly to how you need it.